# Google Maps Engine API Hello World Example in PHP causing MapItem not found

Tags: php, google-maps, google-api-php-client, google-maps-engine

I am trying to work through getting the PHP client for Google Map to work correctly.

I've downloaded a local copy of the GoogleAPI PHP Client from [GitHub:https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client).

I am running PHP v5.4 on IIS8. The GoogleAPI was installed in the PHP Include folder, under **GoogleAPI**.

PHP works correctly with all my other scripts.

I am trying get the example to work from [Maps-Engine Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/hello-world).

```html
<?php
ini_set('display_errors','on');

require('GoogleAPI/autoload.php');

//require_once 'GoogleAPI/src/Google/Client.php';
//require_once 'Google/Service/MapsEngine.php';

$apiKey = "API Key";

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google-PhpMapsEngineSample/1.0");
$client->setDeveloperKey($apiKey);

$service = new Google_Service_MapsEngine($client);

$optParams = array('maxResults' => 500, 'version' => 'published');
$results = $service->tables_features->listTablesFeatures("12421761926155747447-06672618218968397709", $optParams);

print_r($results);

?>
```

The only changes to the code example were the API Key, load the Google Autoloader and comment out the require_once directives.

The output I receive is:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Google_Service_MapsEngine_MapItem' not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4\includes\GoogleAPI\src\Google\Service\MapsEngine.php on line 4702
```

MapsEngine:4702 extends the Google_Service_MapsEngine_MapItem class. The Google_Service_MapsEngine_MapItem class extends the Google_Model class defined in Model.php file.

Comment: Are you commenting out the require_once('MapsEngine.php') line when you run this?

Comment: Yes. It is being loaded with the AUTOLOADER. I've verified that by echoing the class names in the autoloader when they are called.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I had the same problem.

There is a bug in the google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/MapsEngine.php file.  The class Google_Service_MapsEngine_MapFolder which exends the Google_Service_MapsEngine_MapItem is declared before the class Google_Service_MapsEngine_MapItem is declared.

I switch the order of the 2 classes in the MapsEngine.php file and that fixed the problem.  This shows the correct order for the classes.

```
class Google_Service_MapsEngine_MapItem extends Google_Model
{
  protected $internal_gapi_mappings = array(
  );
  public $type;


  public function setType($type)
  {
    $this->type = $type;
  }
  public function getType()
  {
    return $this->type;
  }
}

class Google_Service_MapsEngine_MapFolder extends Google_Service_MapsEngine_MapItem
{
  protected $collection_key = 'defaultViewport';
  protected $internal_gapi_mappings = array(
  );
  protected $contentsType = 'Google_Service_MapsEngine_MapItem';
  protected $contentsDataType = 'array';
  public $defaultViewport;
  public $expandable;
  public $key;
  public $name;
  public $visibility;
  protected function gapiInit()
  {
    $this->type = 'folder';
  }

  public function setContents($contents)
  {
    $this->contents = $contents;
  }
  public function getContents()
  {
    return $this->contents;
  }
  public function setDefaultViewport($defaultViewport)
  {
    $this->defaultViewport = $defaultViewport;
  }
  public function getDefaultViewport()
  {
    return $this->defaultViewport;
  }
  public function setExpandable($expandable)
  {
    $this->expandable = $expandable;
  }
  public function getExpandable()
  {
    return $this->expandable;
  }
  public function setKey($key)
  {
    $this->key = $key;
  }
  public function getKey()
  {
    return $this->key;
  }
  public function setName($name)
  {
    $this->name = $name;
  }
  public function getName()
  {
    return $this->name;
  }
  public function setVisibility($visibility)
  {
    $this->visibility = $visibility;
  }
  public function getVisibility()
  {
    return $this->visibility;
  }
}
```